# SSL Error for cPanel secondary ip with backlinks going to it

Tags: apache, ssl, ip, cpanel, portforwarding

as an amauture i do give my apoligied now if my terms and phrases are not correct.

I have a dedicated server with 2 ip addresses, One of the ips is running a website while the second is spare and just redirects to the website from cPanels default homepage using meta refresh.

The issue is when ever a user goes to a backlinked domain and visits the https version of the link it throws this following error:

An error occurred during a connection to xyz.com. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Is it possible to route all incoming traffic to that ip that is heading for the ssl port to the main server ip /domain that has the ssl assigned to it.

right now i just have it doing this

```
<html><head><meta refresh="https://TheMainWebsite.com"></head></html>
```

and that works for all the http traffic going to xyz.com but as soon as you add the https version your instantly hit with the error and it does this even if you use the ip instead of the domain so for eaxmple:  https://123.1.1.123

Any help would be greatly appreicated, Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your site xyz.com, has not installed correctl SSL in Cpanel.

The site should have a own ip (it's possible use shared certificate but not good idea)

1. Login to your WHM, "Generate an SSL Certificate and Signing Request"
2. Go to "SSL/TLS" section and open "Install a SSL Certificate and Setup the Domain".
3. Got to "Install an SSL Certificate on a Domain"
4. Put domain name on inputa text "Domain" & and click on autofill button.
5. Click on Install